# Is it possible to create nested objects with the same _id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

As the title says.

For example this is my Schema:

```
var contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    address: String,
    email: String,
    addedNumbers: [
        { phone: String,
        number: Number,
        default: Boolean
        }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible that all objects inside the addedNumbers array have the same _id as root?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because ID means `unique identifier`, so by definition you can't have a multiple-unique identifier. The real question is, why would you need to do that in the first place?

Comment: The addedNumbers array usually has multiple objects containing phone numbers but only one has default = true. I'm saving those objects with true value and I want to somehow compare the object to the contact and display it in my html file Thats why i thought if the ID could be the same so I can do the "if ( contact._id.equals(defaultObject._id) )"

Comment: You can certainly leave the _id off of the sub documents.

Comment: what do you seek to achieve by having the sub documents have the same _id as the parent document

Answer (score 0):

`_id` mean "unique identifier" it should be unique.